# How come the read function in this C program can read chinese characters and other not ASCII values?

Tags: c, terminal, character-encoding, character

I don't understand why I'm able to read() every character I type on my terminal but if I try to assign a non ascii value to a C variable it doesn't work.
There are three main questions below this code ->

```
int main (){

    int fd;
    fd = open("./dog.txt",O_RDONLY);
    //contents of dog.txt -> 漢è hello

    ssize_t r;
    char b;

    while( (r = read( fd, &b, sizeof(b))) > 0 ){
            
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,&b, sizeof(b));
            
    }

    printf("\n");

    //OUTPUT :  漢è hello

    
}
```

However something like this is not accepted :

```
int main (){

  unsigned int test = '漢';

  write(STDOUT_FILENO,&test,sizeof(test));

  printf("\n");

}
```

The c program receives a series of bytes one at a time and then it sends them back one at a time to the terminal through the write system call ( the buffer in the example is 1 Byte ).

1. But how does the terminal know that it must "interpret" the chinese character as a group of 3 Bytes when I write()? Considering that I'm writing 1 Byte at a time it could have well interpreted each single Byte as three different 8 Bytes characters.
2. Is there some sort of cooperation between the process and the terminal to make this possible?
3. Could someone provide a straight to the point explanation of character encodings in both terminal and programs (in this case C)?

Comment: Because the byte order is reversed? In the second case a (disk) file output has `A2 BC E6 00`. In the first case the file has `E6 BC A2 C3  A8 20 68 65  6C 6C 6F`

Comment: See my recent answer re. utf-8: [Searching letters in the two dimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887619/5382650) It talks about why you have to use `"漢"` instead of `'漢'`

Answer (score 1):

> But how does the terminal know that it must "interpret" the chinese character as a group of 3 Bytes when I write() ? ...

The terminal sees a stream of bytes and tries to decode that **stream** into characters irrespectively of whether they were written with one `write` call or multiple calls.

The exact way it decodes the stream depends on the encoding used in your system. I assume that your system uses UTF-8, because that's an encoding where 漢 is represented with the sequence of the three bytes `e6 bc a2` (here in hexadecimal). In UTF-8, the number of bytes the character takes is determined by its first byte. UTF-8 is actually ingenious for that and a few other reasons. For details you should refer the [Wikipedia page on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

> Is there some sort of cooperation between the process and the terminal to make this possible ?

The process and the terminal both follow the system convention about which encoding to use. On UNIX systems that's determined by the value of the `LANG`, `LC_ALL` (or some other) environment variables. This might be seen as 'cooperation', but there's definitively no two-way communication between them other than the respective byte streams.

> However something like this is not accepted : ...

It actually *may* work on some implementations. However the exact meaning of character literals (single-quoted strings) with multi-byte characters or multiple characters is not defined per the standard.

What *is* going to work on most UNIX systems though, is using a string literal and saving the source file in UTF-8:

```
char test[] = "漢";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, test, strlen(test));
printf("\n");
```