# In C, how to print UTF-8 char if given its bytes in char variables?

Tags: c, utf-8, wchar-t, wchar

If I have c1, c2 as char variables (such that c1c2 would be the byte sequences for the UTF-8 character), how do I create and print the UTF-8 character?

Similarly for the 3 and 4 byte UTF-8 characters?

I've been trying all kinds of approaches with `mbstowcs()` but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: My recent answer on utf-8 may help: [Searching letters in the two dimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887619/5382650)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: In general with UTF-8: "char" is just a wrong name for "byte". A real Unicode char should be represented by a string. MB doesn't usually help.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write a working example. 
When `c1` is `'\xce'` and `c2` is `'\xb8'`, the result is `θ`.
It turns out that I have to call `setlocale` before using `mbstowcs`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
 
int main()
{
   char* localeInfo = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
   printf("Locale information set to %s\n", localeInfo);
   
   const char c1 = '\xce';
   const char c2 = '\xb8';
   int byteCount = 2;

   char* mbS = (char*) malloc(byteCount + 1);
   mbS[0] = c1; 
   mbS[1] = c2; 
   mbS[byteCount] = 0; //null terminator
   printf("Directly using printf: %s\n", mbS);
   
   
   int requiredSize = mbstowcs(NULL, mbS, 0); 
   printf("Output size including null terminator is %d\n\n", requiredSize +1);
   
   wchar_t *wideOutput = (wchar_t *)malloc( (requiredSize +1) * sizeof( wchar_t ));
   
   int len = mbstowcs(wideOutput , mbS, requiredSize +1 ); 
   if(len == -1){
       printf("Failed conversion!");
   }else{
       printf("Converted %d character(s). Result: %ls\n", len, wideOutput );
   }
   return 0;
    
}
```

Output:

```
Locale information set to en_US.utf8
Directly using printf: θ
Output size including null terminator is 2

Converted 1 character(s). Result: θ
```

For 3 or 4 byte utf8 characters, one can use a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have c1, c2 as char variables (such that c1c2 would be the byte sequences for the UTF-8 character), how do I create and print the UTF-8 character?

They *are* already an UTF-8 character. You would just print them.

```
putchar(c1);
putchar(c2);
```

It's up to *your terminal* or whatever device you are using to *display* the output to properly understand and render the UTF-8 encoding. This is unrelated to encoding used by *your program* and unrelated to wide characters.

> Similarly for the 3 and 4 byte UTF-8 characters?

You would output them.

---

*If* your terminal or the device you are sending the bytes to does not understand UTF-8 encoding, then *you* have to convert the bytes to something the device understands. Typically, you would use an external library for that, like `iconv`. Alternatively, you could `setlocale("C.utf-8")` then convert your bytes to `wchar_t`, then `setlocale("C.your_target_encoding")` *and then* convert the bytes to that encoding or output the bytes with `%ls`. All `%ls` does (on common systems) is it [converts the string back to multibyte](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.33/source/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c#L1215) and *then* outputs it. Wide stream outputting to terminal does the same, first converts, then outputs.