# How to use tolower or toupper with a special character such as Å

Tags: c, windows, char

While programming in C, I encountered a problem regarding the tolower and toupper functions.
I want to print an upper case 'Å', and then using the tolower function to print a lower case 'Å' ('å').

First, I declare a variable int x, and give it a value of 143 (because in the ASCII, Å is given that integer). When I then print out x using printf("%c", x) I will get an 'Å'. I also want to print an 'å' (a lower case Å), and to do so, I used the tolower function. However, I do not get an 'å', I only get 2 Å's and I do not understand why. If someone could explain it to me I will be grateful. Also, I am new to programming. Thus I might not use the correct terms at all times, but hopefully you will understand!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

int x = 143;

printf("Upper case is %c\n", x);
printf("Lower case is %c\n", tolower(x));

return 0;
}
```

Output:

Upper case is Å
Lower case is Å

I also tried this, but the output was the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){

int x = 143;
int y;

y = tolower(x);

printf("Upper case is %c\n", x);
printf("Lower case is %c\n", y);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Å` is a variable length UTF-8 codepoint. It is _two_ chars (i.e. `0xC3, 0x85`). So, it can _not_ work with `toupper/tolower` or other `ctype.h` functions. You may need to devise your own conversion table. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 Also, see [one of] my answer: [Searching letters in the two dimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887619/5382650)

Comment: Use wide characters instead.

Comment: Might need `setlocale()` first too.

Comment: @CraigEstey it may work if the particular locale has this letter.

Comment: Alexander Jonsson, In the C standard _locale_, `tolower(143)` is 143 when code is ASCII.  Call `setlocale()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: [tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower)

> **Return value**
>
> Lowercase version of ch or unmodified ch if no lowercase version is listed in the current C locale.

Since you get the unmodified value, that means no lowercase version was found.

To fix the problem, a solution might be to set the appropriate C locale (via [setlocale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale)).

Furthermore, i would suggest to read the following two articles, since the value `143` is not ASCII but Extended ASCII (and to get a better understanding what `setlocale` is good for):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII